# Print Code 128 (GS1) with Zebra/Bixolon printer

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, barcode-printing, gs1-128, bixolon-printer

I’m printing barcodes with a mobile printer. In particular, it is a Bixolon SPP-R200II that is programmed using CPCL.

My challenge now is this: The code to print is a License Plate GS1 NVE (also known as EAN 128 and a few other permutations). As an example, take `00340435081776152901`, which is usually rendered like “(00) 340435081776152901” (or very similar). Using an [online barcode generator](https://barcode.tec-it.com/), the result is:

[image: Generated barcode]

I can also confirm visually that this is the same as what I found “in real life” from a different source, printed on a label. However, when I try to reproduce this with CPCL, I use the following piece of code:

```
VBARCODE UCCEAN128 10 3 200 92 560 00340435081776152901
```

This results in the following; this code was printed and scanned and enhanced a bit, it’s blurry but can be read by my barcode scanner:

[image: Printed barcode (scanned)]

Now you can quite easily see that these barcodes look different. The barcode from my printer is considerably wider, it contains more bars. However, my barcode scanner app (I use [Barcode Scanner from Cognex](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=cognex%20barcode%20scanner&c=apps)) reads both with the same value and the same type “Code 128 (GS1)”.

The barcode type that was used here is `UCCEAN128`; note that I could change that to `128`, but that would result in something identified as “Code 128” instead. Can the printer generate a barcode that is equivalent to the first image above?

Comment: Apparently [from the manual](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf) you can't select the subset using this printer language.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part about the two different representations: When you look at the bars and count zeroes and ones and look it up in a [Code 128 documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128), you will see that the first barcode is:

1. Start Code C
2. FNC 1
3. 00
4. 34
5. ...

It encodes two decimal digits in each 11 bits, which is quite clever considering the input consists of an even number of digits. The second barcode is:

1. Start Code B
2. FNC 1
3. 0
4. 0
5. 3
6. 4
7. ...

It is longer because it encodes each decimal digits on its own in 11 bits.